# double "this" in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging

When trying to debug a JS problem in the browser I set a breakpoint. When it breaks I went to the console window I started typing "this" and to my surprise the auto-complete choices popped up with not one but two "this" options. Is this normal behaviour under some circumstances or representative of a problem?

[image]

Comment: The million dollar question is, do they have different values ?

Comment: I've personally found the chrome debugger to be quite buggy; it would report stale or completely incorrect values at times. Have you tried it in firefox?

Comment: @adeneo .... they appear to point to the same object

Comment: @univerio I haven't tried it in FF but with that shiny new look and feel in the latest build I'll happily try that now :)

Comment: sadly I can't recreate the same JS error in the in Firefox; happily the error is in third party library and backing off the beta release fixes the problem in both browsers ... albeit doesn't solve the mystery around the double "this" ... will have to solve this another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just closing this with an answer as I can no longer reproduce this anymore.

Comment: I suggest you delete the question instead. It has no use. You will save time for 3 other stackoverflow moderator/reviewers!

Comment: sorry i just tried and it wouldn't let me delete the answer or the question.